# get a dataTable with a message "emptyTable", if the aaData is an empty array?

Tags: datatables

I am doing a ajax request to the server to get the data.When the array is empty, I want it to be displayed in a table row "emptyTable". I get message "emptyTable", if not used aoColumnDefs, but I'm getting warning "Requested unknown parameter ... " . I do not want to receive a warning!

```
var searchTable = $('#baseTasks').dataTable({
        bFilter: false, bInfo: false, "bLengthChange": false,
        scrollY:"600px",scrollCollapse: true, paging:false,
        "aaData": tasks,
        "aoColumns": [
         { "mData": "name"
         },{"mData": "schoolClass"
         },{"mData": "complexity"
         },{"mData": "author"
    }]
});
```

if I use aoColumnDefs, I do not get warning, but I get an empty table without message "emptyTable".

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
           {
                "mData": null,
               "sDefaultContent": null,
                "aTargets": [ -1 ]
            }],
```

How do I get a table with a message "emptyTable", if the aaData is an empty array?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Run the code below for demonstration.

```js
var tasks = [
   {
       "name": "Tiger Nixon",
       "schoolClass": "System Architect",
       "complexity": "$320,800",
       "author": "2011\/04\/25"
   },
   {
       "name": "Garrett Winters",
       "schoolClass": "Accountant",
       "complexity": "$170,750",
       "author": "2011\/07\/25"
   }
];

var tasksEmpty = [];

$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "data": tasksEmpty,
    "columns": [
         { "data": "name"},
         { "data": "schoolClass" },
         { "data": "complexity"},
         { "data": "author" }    
     ],
    "searching": false, 
    "info": false, 
    "lengthChange": false,
    "scrollY":"600px",
    "scrollCollapse": true, 
    "paging":false,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Most likely cause of `Requested unknown parameter` error is that your data is not structured properly or some of the properties (`name`, `schoolClass`, `complexity` or `author`) are not found.

Your data should have the following structure. Make sure that every array item has all the properties required.

```
var tasks = [
   {
       "name": "Tiger Nixon",
       "schoolClass": "System Architect",
       "complexity": "$320,800",
       "author": "2011\/04\/25"
   },
   {
       "name": "Garrett Winters",
       "schoolClass": "Accountant",
       "complexity": "$170,750",
       "author": "2011\/07\/25"
   }
];
```

Also please note that your code uses parameters for different versions of DataTables. Although newer DataTables library is backward-compatible, I have updated your code to use initialization parameters for the most recent version. Please see [this migration guide](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Add the below line of code to your datatable with your message set to `sEmptyTable`.

```
oLanguage: {
            "sEmptyTable": "No data found.",
           }
```